# passing username/password from sencha to restapi

Tags: json, extjs

I have used sencha touch 2 as client for one of my mobiles apps, I have used django-tastypie RESTFUL api to handle client requests . Now i need to send username/password with request like below

> domainame/api/v1/entry/?format=jsonp&username=admin&password=admin&_dc=1336968929898&type=new&city=ABC&date=31-03-2012

Below is my sample code,

```
 handler: function() {
                        Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'http://domainaname/api/v1/entry/?format=jsonp&username=admin&password=admin',
    method: 'GET',
    withCredentials: true,
    useDefaultXhrHeader: false,
    params:{
        type: 'new',
        city: 'ABC',
        date: '31-03-2012',
    },

    callback: function(response, successful) {
        if (successful) {
            Ext.Msg.alert('Success', 'We got yours');
        } else {
            Ext.Msg.alert('Fail', 'It didnt work!');
        }
    }
```

I don't want username/password to be visible .

**Type,city,date are filter option of query**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just change the `method` type

```
'GET' -> 'POST'
```

and then send your `username` and `password` in following way ..

```
.....
params: {
   username: Ext.getCmp('userId').getValue(),
   password: Ext.getCmp('userPswdId').getValue()
},
.....
```

Comment: POST will insert new record as per rule of RESTAPI

Comment: Have you tried using POST? I think you should try it first to check the result.

Comment: ya tried , POST simply add type: 'new',
        city: 'ABC',
        date: '31-03-2012'          please advise me

Comment: type,city and date are filter options of the query